# Why my form not getting posted to the right controller action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I distinguish between these 2 routes in my area registration?

These are the last 2 routes in that area registration.

The first route is when the view is loaded. Works fine.

First route loads a form which then get posted to the same controller but different action.

I never get OK from controller. It might not hitting controller due to routing issue.

What I am missing?

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Load",
        "app/respond/{Id}",
        new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Index" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Update",
        "app/respond/{action}",
        new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Update" }
    );
```

This is how the form looks:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Respond", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmUpdate" }))
{
   //all form fields go here
}
```

This is how the posting is done:

```
$('#frmUpdate').submit(function () {
    //verify all field values

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.s == 'OK')
                alert("Success! Response updated");
            else
                alert("Sorry! Update failed.");//this is what I get
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(MyModel model)
{
    return Json(new { s = "OK", m = "Hi from controller" });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distinguish between those 2 routes because they follow absolutely the same url pattern `app/respond/something`. You didn't put any constraint on `something` so the first route will always match.

If you want to have any chance of the routing system being able of distinguishing you need to use a constraint, for example let's say that an `{id}` must contain only numbers:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Load",
    "app/respond/{id}",
    new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Index" },
    new { id = @"[0-9]+" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Update",
    "app/respond/{action}",
    new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Update" }
);
```

Now when you request `app/respond/123` the Index action will be called and when you invoke `app/respond/FooBar` the `FooBar` action will be called. And if you request `app/respond` the `Update` action will be invoked.

Comment: In my case both case has exact same url but I have different values for action. I can't add constraint on id because second route has same id as well since it is the same url - all because I am keeping the user on the same page after form submission. I just show user result async way.

Comment: I load a form which gets submitted. Upon submission, I do some db action and then want to disaply the result to user. This is done async using jquery. The action to load is different from the action to do update. Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Projapati, with your current routes setup and without a route constraint you are not doing it right.

Comment: I changed the update route from "app/respond/{action}" to "app/respond/update" without adding constraint on id. Now I am able to hit both urls. Working it seems.